# Is it possible to prevent content types from other SharePoint online sites to recognized?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type

When a user from Department A recieve an email from Department B and either open the attachment or save it in SP, it automatically attempts to tag it with the existing Content-Type and Metadata (from Dept B).
Problem is that content type and metadata do not exist in Dept A, and it auto assigns the wrong content type.
Is there a way to prevent SP from recognizing Content Types coming from different sites?

P.S.
We don't wan to use Content Hub.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, this issue will occur when you add the related content type in target library.

If you save the attachment in the library which use default content type, SharePoint will not recognize it.

Comment: The Content-Type does not exist on the source destination, however, some of the Metadata does. So making it worst it set the wrong content type with some of the irrelevant metadata. :(

Comment: Don't allow other content types in DocA and make it use default content type, then compare the result.